# How to show(Bringtofront) an already opened Mdi child form from another Mdi child form?

Tags: c#, mdi, mdichild

In my applcation i have 4 forms ,form1 is a mdi container and remaining forms are it childs,
in form1 i am opening all child form in its load event. in child form2 i have a button which will switch to childform3.my problem is how to show childform3(which is already opened) from button in childform2

```
               form1:

               Form2 formchild1;
               Form3 formchild2;
               Form4 formchild3;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        if (formchild2 == null)
        {
            formchild2 = new Form3();
        }
        formchild2.MdiParent = this;
        formchild2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        formchild2.Show();
        //formchild2.BringToFront();


        if (formchild3 == null)
        {
            formchild3 = new Form4();
        }
        formchild3.MdiParent = this;
        formchild3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        formchild3.Show();


        if (formchild1 == null)
        {
            formchild1 = new Form2();
        }
        formchild1.MdiParent = this;
        formchild1.Show();
        formchild1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        formchild1.BringToFront();


        }


        form2:

        Form3 formchild2;
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //what i have to write hare..
            //formchild2 = new Form3();
            //formchild2.MdiParent = this.ParentForm;

            //formchild2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            //formchild2.Show();
            //formchild2.BringToFront();

    }
```

Comment: if i initialize new instances in button it will create new form instance on every button click.

Comment: Make one child form aware of another is a very iffy practice.  Put this code in the MDI parent form instead, it necessarily already knows about all your child forms.  Just call it from the child, something like ((MyMDIParent)this.MdiParent).FooBar().

Comment: i didn't get your explanation  please kindly send few more codes thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you create your form2 (Please change your variable names, it took a while to figure out that formchild1 was actually form2), you need to instantiate the form2 instance

```
if (formchild1 == null)
{
    formchild1 = new Form2(/*Either pass in a Form3 here*/);
}
formchild1.formChild2 = formchild2; //Or make formChild2 public member
formchlid1.SetForm(formChild2); //Or make a method that sets it
formchild1.MdiParent = this;
formchild1.Show();
formchild1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
formchild1.BringToFront();
```

Then to show it again you can just do

```
formchild2.BringToFront();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
childform3 childform3=new childform3;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!childform3.IsDisposed)
            childform3.Select();
        else
            childform3= new frmSearch();
        childform3.MdiParent = ParentForm;
        childform3.Show();
    }
```